# RegExp: Match '3' words of a list, not repeating

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing an applications in which the user is asked to write, for example, three words of a list (the order is not important).

I can try something like this:

```
\^ [ itemA | itemB | itemC | itemD | item E | item F] {3}
```

But obviously, the user can write three times the same item. Is there a way to archieve it using a regular expression and evaluate it using a single "match" function?

I'm using JavaScript, of course.

Thank you guys!

---

Excuse me, let me clarify.

I have the following screen:

[image: Example]

So the user have 7 possible answers, and he have to write three of them.

Of course, this "screen" have a LOT of kind of questions in which a regex worked very well to evaluate it,  but in this one, I don't know if it is enought.

Thank you guys.

Comment: your question is not clear?

Comment: provide some examples (inputs and expected results)

Comment: Even if you *are* accepting multiple inputs as a single string, there's not really a use-case for attempting an all-in-one regex validation.  What you gain in ninja points you lose in usability - if you wanted to give the user meaningful feedback you'd need some javascript logic regardless.  Perhaps you are over thinking the problem - why not [keep it simple](https://jsfiddle.net/Emissary/wo7n5j3L/)?

Comment: Thank you very much, Emissary. The main reasson I wanted to evaluate it using a single regexp was because the questions are writted by users in JSON object's, so there's a field called "regexp" that is evaluated with "match" function in the controller. Of course, I can use your code (thank you!) but it means that the app's code have to be updated, and this means a new release. Anyway, thank you very much, your answer was useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check that I've understood, you're attempting to validate that:

1. The user has entered exactly three items,
2. Each item is a member of a pre-defined list
3. And each item is unique?

That's not a good fit for a regular expression. You can meet the first two requirements, but it's much simpler to do the third one directly using JavaScript or something similar.

If you really want to do it this way, you can do this:

`^(itemA|itemB|itemC|itemD|item E|itemF) (?!\1)(itemA|itemB|itemC|itemD|item E|itemF) (?!\1)(?!\2)(itemA|itemB|itemC|itemD|item E|itemF)`

This uses a [negative lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

1. First item must match itemA-itemF
2. Second item must first *not* match whatever the first item was, and also match itemA-itemF
3. Third item must not match the first item, not match the second item, and also match itemA-itemF.

Comment: nice negative lookahead... but try these on console: `"a b c d".match(/^(a|b|c) (?!\1)(a|b|c) (?!\1)(?!\2)(a|b|c)/)` and this `"a b e c d".match(/^(a|b|c) (?!\1)(a|b|c) (?!\1)(?!\2)(a|b|c)/)`. are items supposed to be in order?

Comment: I don't know what the behaviour is meant to be after the three items.

Comment: I did a quick test in console and it returns `["itemA itemB itemC","itemA","itemB","itemC"]` when tested for `"itemA itemB itemC"`.

Comment: Thank you very uch, Bennett!!! I will study your code, it looks like the answer must be something like that.

Comment: The main reasson cause I don't wanted to do it using Javascript it's because the questions are writted by users and stored via JSON objects. There's a field called "regex" that is evaluated with "match function". If I do it using Javascript it means that I had to update the controller's code and it implies an app update on Google Play Store. Thank you very much again!